# I'm getting "[errno 22] Invalid argument: 'test.txt\r'

Tags: python, file, text, error-handling

I'm experimenting with a python program that will allow you to edit text files, I will use this feature later on in other programs, but I get the error: [errno 22] Invealid argument: 'test.txt\r'.  Also I never added \r to test.txt.  Here is my code:

```
 def menu():
     print("Type in the full name of the text file you would like to add to.")
     file1 = input()
     with open(file1, "br") as add:
         print("What do you want to write?")
         text = input()
         add.write(text)
 menu()
```

Okay, new problem.  I edited the code so that now it says `file1 = input().strip()` and it worked fine ALL up until I got another error.  The error is: `io:UnsupportedOperation: write`.  The error says it's in line 7 in the part that says `add.write(text)`.

Nevermind, I changed the with `open(file1, "br")` to with `open(file1, "a")` and it works fine now.  THANKS FOR ALL OF YOUR HELP GUYS!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
file1 = input().strip()
```

`input()` returns the new line at the end and that makes the filename invalid.

Answer (score 1):

use `input().strip()` to remove the trailing new-lines from your input, it might have came due to running your program in terminal or cmd.

Comment: Okay, I was using cmd, but one more thing, I'm new to Python, so could you please explain what the ".strip()" part does?

Comment: strip() removes all the trailing and leading `\n`, `\r\n`, `\n` from the string.

Comment: @CharlieKimzey in your case even `rstrip()` will work fine, it removes only trailing whitespaces.

Comment: It doesn't just remove newlines, but all kinds of whitespace.